# Help me to select a NoSQL Package

Tags: php, nosql

I'm completely new to NoSQL [have just read some articles on NoSQL] and want to develop a simple application using it.
Please help me to select a NoSQL system
The system should have these features

- SQL like Select query (select col1, col2 from tbl where col1>10)
- SQL like insert query (it will be better if it has Auto increment feature)
- It should be compatible to use with PHP

Comment: I think you're asking for something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). Simple to use, fast, reliable and quite powerful. Also, there's a nice driver for PHP.

MongoDB is "NoSQL", schema-free and document-oriented. Different terminology is used, but as a beginner you can think it has collections instead of tables, documents instead of rows and fields instead of columns. Inserting and selecting is quite simple:

```
// Select some documents.

$cursor = $db->my_collection->find(array(
    'field1' => array('$gt' => 10), // where field1 > 10
), array(
    'field1', 'field2', // which fields to fetch
))->sort(array(
    'field3' => -1, // sort descending by field3
));

while($document = $cursor->getNext())
{
    // ...
}

// Insert a document.

$db->my_collection->insert(array(
    'field1' => 'a',
    'field2' => 2,
    'field3' => 14.8,
));
```

Comment: +1 for an correct answer, can you tell me what is the `table/collection` name in the above answer ?

Comment: Collection name is "my_collection". $db->my_collection works as a getter, you can write $db->selectCollection('my_collection') if you want. Also, official documentation of MongoDB at php.net has a bunch of examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think most of the nosql dbs support creation of collections/tables/column families and are compatible with php.
You better need to look at what kind of data you want to store and retrieve to decide which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

Does your design have many inter-relating entities, or is it relatively few large tables?

If the latter then I'd wholeheartedly agree that a document oriented database such as **Mongo** or Apache **CouchDB** would suit.

If the former then you may want to look at **neo4j** -- which has a node graph approach.  The introductory videos on the site are worth watching.  The key benefit of a graph oriented solution is that relationships can be defined on an instance by instance basis (rather than the class level entity approach of a RDBMS)

For admin and simple data entry:  CouchDB and neo4j both have easy to use web based front ends; Mongo has phpmoadmin (3rd party) application.

Disclaimer -- I've not attempted to see how any of the above scales, my biggest application [Couch with Ruby on Rails] has only approx 1000 entries.

good luck !